# Django redundant migration files are being created

Tags: python, django

```
class Agency(models.Model):
   uuid = models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4())
   name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Name',
    max_length=50
)
```

Whenever, I am applying `python manage.py makemigrations` new migration files are being created. It is worth mentioning that, I am not touching models.py file.

The migration file content is.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('dashboard', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='agency',
        name='uuid',
        field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.UUID('890eb162-c485-49f0-87a6-ebc3e95a12b3'), editable=False),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='agencycontract',
        name='uuid',
        field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.UUID('f6500cbe-69ee-42c0-ad1e-80377f2a9dcf'), editable=False),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='contractproduct',
        name='uuid',
        field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.UUID('7bc66e61-c752-4333-b508-14b53c903e83'), editable=False),
    ),
]
```

I know that, hence I am using uuid function that is why those are being created. How do I stop that file creation? Before that is that really necessary to stop this migration file creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)  # Instead of uuid.uuid4()
```